# Regular expression to filter 2 urls

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Can I have a filter (or match) only the below mentioned 2 urls by using Regular expression?

http://www.domain.com/owner/Marketing and http://www.domain.com/owner/getinfo )?

**UPDATE** Usage is as below.

```
 <rule name="Skip HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="I need regex here" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="OFF" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If I put this way,Will it work?

```
 <match url="(Marketing|getinfo)" ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: why can't you just use an `if...or...`? I can understand that most of the url matches, but why then can you not just check the last part, ie; the part after the last slash?

Comment: @pythonian29033 I need to put this on url rewrite model on web.config file.

Comment: ok, lemme see if I can put one together then

Comment: @pythonian29033 I have updated my question.Please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you want, then it is strait forward: `(http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/Marketing | http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/getinfo)`. see http://regex101.com/r/yW3aP9

Comment: Can you remove this part from your regex (i.e. "http://www.domain.com/" with http)? B'cos it is common part.

Comment: @Sampath yes you can, you can also just use the end part like this; `/\/(Marketing|getinfo)$/`, but to be safe you want to at least include the owner part and no dollar sign, cos I'm guessing the page could get parameters posted to it; `/\/owner\/(Marketing|getinfo)/`

Comment: Is this better? `(http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/(?:Marketing|getinfo))` http://regex101.com/r/qD1nC1

Comment: Please can you see my 'UPDATE 2:' and let me know is it correct or not ?

Comment: About update2: if you put it this way it will only match the last part of the URL. If you want to match the whole URL you have to use a regex like the one I gave you. You can use regex101.com in order to test regex patterns, it is a very useful site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipe `|` character for alternation and parenthesis. Add a leading `^` and trailing `$` "binds" the expression to only match the exact URLs with no leading or trailing garbage and escape the slashes (which acts a RegEx delimiters) and dots (`.` which match any character). So:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/(Marketing|getinfo)$/
```

Comment: I beg to differ: $ echo -e "http://www.domain.com/owner/Marketing\nhttp://www.domain.com/owner/getinfo\nhttp://www.domain.com/owner/HR" | perl -nle 'print if /^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/(Marketing|getinfo)$/'
http://www.domain.com/owner/Marketing
http://www.domain.com/owner/getinfo
$

Comment: Please can you see my 'UPDATE 2:' and let me know is it correct or not ?

Comment: Most likely not. By using ^ like that you are asserting that the URL must start with either "Marketing" or "getinfo".

Comment: Then you're saying that the URL has to contain either "Marketing" or "getinfo" anywhere in it, which may or may not be good enough for this specific case...

Answer (score 1):

ok this one seems to work,

```
/http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/owner\/(Marketing|getinfo)/
```

but regexpal is not matching the strings up when you compare the entire string with a carett and dollar sign `^$`, maybe a more experienced person will know why

Comment: Can you remove http and www.domain.com part from your regex.B'cos it is common for all.

Comment: Perhaps you have leading or trailing whitespaces or slashes? Which context are trying it in?

Comment: the OP's probably going to be posting to the page with the suffix `getinfo`, which should be self explanatory. . . so it would be a bad idea to put a `$` at the end. also this is being matched by a value sent directly from the browser, we don't have to worry about whitespace, the server will ignore it

Comment: Please can you see my 'UPDATE 2:' and let me know is it correct or not ?

Comment: you have to remove the `^` that represents the start of the line, you can test your regex here: http://regexpal.com/ and put the string you want your regex to match with in the bottom, it will be highlighted if the regex matches the string

Comment: oh, my bad! but regular expressions have it's own set of rules, outside of programming languages, it should be generic